# how to check flow of bot in rasa (static bot)?

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, rasa

I'm working with rasa chat bot and after writing stories(static flow). How do i insure that, flow is working properly or not? currently i'm testing each path manually!!!

I want to check with all the possibility and want to make this task automated!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a story using a specific yml file starting with test and running `rasa test` it test the chatbot on the defined story. Here the documentation: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/testing-your-assistant/

Comment: I saw that one but that is for rasa 3.x only, unfortunately I'm using rasa legacy!!!!

Comment: I am thinking to create Tree with each and every possibilities!!!! Not sure whether it'll work or not!!!!!!